# Entspringt “Widerstand ist zwecklos” einer Bedeutungsverschiebung?

Tags: etymology

Immer wieder ruft der Bösewicht

> Widerstand ist zwecklos!

nachdem er den Helden gefesselt, oder dessen Geliebte in seine Gewalt gebracht hat. Dieser Satz erscheint mir durchaus richtig und es sind auch viele ähnliche denkbar.
In den meisten Fällen sind jedoch sowohl der Zweck als auch der Sinn des Widerstandes klar erkennbar. Was der Bösewicht meint ist:

> Widerstand ist vergeblich!

Hat *zwecklos* sich die Hauptbedeutung *vergeblich* im Laufe der Jahrhunderte einverleibt, oder umfasste es sie schon immer?

Auch der Duden definiert:

> ohne Sinn; nutzlos, vergeblich
>    (seltener) keinen bestimmten Zweck erfüllend; ohne bestimmte Absicht

und bestätigt so mein Gefühl, dass die mutmaßlich ursprüngliche Bedeutung völlig in den Hintergrund tritt.

Comment: Diese Frage darf einfach nicht sein, ohne dass jemand [dieses Bild](http://www.rbg.ul.schule-bw.de/elektronik/Bilder/Widerstand%20zwecklos.JPG) zitiert. Zitat des Titels!

Comment: Wäre hier nicht zu klären, ob "Widerstand ist zwecklos" zuerst da war, oder die allgemeine Bedeutung von "kein Zweck". Schließlich wird die Formulierung "Es hat keinen Zweck" o.ä. auch allgemein verwendet, um auszudrücken, dass etwas keine Wirkung zeigen wird, also vergeblich ist, obwohl selbstverständlich eine *Absicht* (und somit zumindest ein beabsichtigter Zweck) vorliegt.

Comment: Der Widerstand ist zwecklos, weil er offensichtlich vergeblich wäre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das scheint mir hier eher einen psychologischen als einen sprachlichen Grund zu haben.

„Widerstand ist vergeblich“ sagt aus „Dein Widerstand ist sinnvoll, aber wird zu keinem Ergebnis führen“, oder „Ich respektiere deine Intelligenz, und du hast recht, es zumindest zu versuchen.“

„Widerstand ist zwecklos“ sagt aus „Ich habe soviel Macht über dich, dass es von vornherein sinnlos ist, es überhaupt zu versuchen“, oder auch „Du bist ein Idiot when du es für sinnvoll hältst, es zu versuchen.“

Also wesentlich mehr einschüchternd.

Answer (score 5):

Die Bedeutung von zwecklos darf man hier nicht zu eng sehen, denn wo verfolgt ein Bemühen nicht irgendeinen Zweck, solche Fälle sind schwer vorstellbar.
Da *zwecklos* sonst eher unbrauchbar wäre muss man davon ausgehen, dass vergeblich immer schon darin enthalten war.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, dass *Zweck* neben der ursprünglichen/eigentlichen Bedeutung *Absicht* auch die zweite Bedeutung *Sinn* hat (z.B. in "das hat keinen Zweck"), und diese es ist, die in *zwecklos* zum Tragen kommt.